# Глобальная обработка ошибок сервера axios (VUE)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, response

Пытаюсь обрабатывать HTTP коды состояния, через AXIOS глобально на VUE,

По типу, если например сервер не может подключиться к БД - возвращает ошибку

```
return $response->withJson(['error' => 'DataBase temporarily unavailable. Vova is dead now', 'reason' => 'invalid_db'], 503);
```

Отлавливаю её в main.js (где и инициализируется AXIOS)

```
Vue.axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  return response.data;
}, function (error) {
  if (error.response.status === 503) {
    console.log('unauthorized, logging out ...');
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

И с одной стороны всё круто, всё отлавливается... Но с другой, я не могу использовать в этой функции Vue и соответственно все дочерние функции. А я бы хотел например передавать в компонент эту ошибку и там её визуализировать. Собственно в этом и вопрос. Или можете предложите другой вариант отслеживания и обработки ошибок. Спасибо)

Comment: Странно, что не можите использовать в этой функции Vue. Мне даже с `fetch`-ем удаётся визуализировать ошибки. Хотя казалось бы какое fetch имеет отношение к Vue? А у Вас же, судя по всему, axios вообще к Vue приколочен. Тем более должно получится. Сделайте тем или иным образом глобальное сво-во Vue error, установите его внутри cвоей функции и показывает в каком угодно компоненте.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо создать функцию, которая будет каждый раз создавать новый экземпляр компонент-сообщения.
В примере, эту функцию я поместил внутрь компонента-Vue, в качестве метода. Но сделал я это для того, чтобы можно было показать наглядно ее работу. На практике же, эту функцию необходимо сделать самостоятельной, в отдельном файле

```js
const message = Vue.component("message", {
  props: ["count"],
  created() {
    window.alert(`Message number ${this.count}`);
  }
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: `<div><button @click="showMessage">Show message</button></div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showMessage() {
      const {
        count
      } = this;
      const Message = Vue.extend(message);
      const component = new Message({
        propsData: {
          count
        }
      });
      component.$mount();
      this.count++;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```